# Combining 2 python lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have 2 python list of dictionaries. First python list looks like below :

```
l1=  [{'compu_method': 'ROTACC', 'aufloesung': '1024'}, 
{'compu_method': 'TMPOUTS', 'aufloesung': '1'}]
```

Second python list looks like this:

```
l2=  [{'signal_name': 'XXXX', 'compu_method': 'ROTACC', 'min_wert': '-500', 'max_wert': '500'},
 {'signal_name': 'YYYY', 'compu_method': 'TMPOUTS', 'min_wert': '-70', 'max_wert': '184'}, 
 {'signal_name': 'ZZZZ', 'compu_method': 'TMPOUTS', 'min_wert': '-70', 'max_wert': '184'}]
```

Both lists have **compu_method** common. I want **aufloesung** from first list for all the **compu_method**  which exists in second list. 
I would like to have a final list like this :

```
[{'signal_name': 'XXXX', 'compu_method': 'ROTACC', 'min_wert': '-500', 'max_wert': '500','aufloesung': '1024'},
 {'signal_name': 'YYYY', 'compu_method': 'TMPOUTS', 'min_wert': '-70', 'max_wert': '184','aufloesung': '1'}, 
 {'signal_name': 'ZZZZ', 'compu_method': 'TMPOUTS', 'min_wert': '-70', 'max_wert': '184','aufloesung': '1'}]
```

I tried below code but it doesnt give the desired output:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
for l in (l1, l2):
    for elem in l:
        d[elem['compu_method']].update(elem)

l3 = d.values()
print(l3)
```

What modification is needed in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a dictionary:

```
d1 = { m['compu_method']: m['aufloesung'] for m in l1}
```

Once you have that, its just a matter of mapping into the new one:

```
for i, m in enumerate(l2):
    l2[i]['aufloesung'] = d1.get(m['compu_method'], None)
```

Should do the trick ...

Comment: `dict.get()` returns `None` by default

Comment: Thanks! I should have seen that one!

Answer (score 2):

Without using other modules, you can try this :

```
for i in l2:
    for j in l1:
        if i['compu_method']==j['compu_method']:
            i['aufloesung']=j['aufloesung']
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[{'signal_name': 'XXXX', 'compu_method': 'ROTACC', 'min_wert': '-500', 'max_wert': '500', 'aufloesung': '1024'}, 
{'signal_name': 'YYYY', 'compu_method': 'TMPOUTS', 'min_wert': '-70', 'max_wert': '184', 'aufloesung': '1'}, 
{'signal_name': 'ZZZZ', 'compu_method': 'TMPOUTS', 'min_wert': '-70', 'max_wert': '184', 'aufloesung': '1'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first transform `l1` to be a dictionary:

```
l1_map = {x["compu_method"]: x["aufloesung"] for x in l1}
```

Then simply update `l2`(or rebuild a new list):

```
for d in l2:
    d["aufloesung"] = l1_map[d["compu_method"]]

print(l2)
# [{'signal_name': 'XXXX', 'compu_method': 'ROTACC', 'min_wert': '-500', 'max_wert': '500', 'aufloesung': '1024'}, {'signal_name': 'YYYY', 'compu_method': 'TMPOUTS', 'min_wert': '-70', 'max_wert': '184', 'aufloesung': '1'}, {'signal_name': 'ZZZZ', 'compu_method': 'TMPOUTS', 'min_wert': '-70', 'max_wert': '184', 'aufloesung': '1'}]
```

Or in terser `**` syntax:

```
[{**d, "aufloesung": l1_map[d["compu_method"]]} for d in l2]
```

This assumes that `"compu_method"` will be present in the transformed dictionary. If you believe a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) could arise, then using [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) as shown in [@ssm's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611447/combining-2-python-lists-of-dictionaries/55611582#55611582) answer will be safer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

```
import copy

l3 = copy.deepcopy(l2)

[ll3.update({'aufloesung':ll1['aufloesung']}) for ll3 in l3 for ll1 in l1 if ll3['compu_method']==ll1['compu_method']]
```

and you get:

```
l3

[{'signal_name': 'XXXX',
  'compu_method': 'ROTACC',
  'min_wert': '-500',
  'max_wert': '500',
  'aufloesung': '1024'},
 {'signal_name': 'YYYY',
  'compu_method': 'TMPOUTS',
  'min_wert': '-70',
  'max_wert': '184',
  'aufloesung': '1'},
 {'signal_name': 'ZZZZ',
  'compu_method': 'TMPOUTS',
  'min_wert': '-70',
  'max_wert': '184',
  'aufloesung': '1'}]
```